# Múltiples columnas con datos de mysql para tabla

Tags: php, mysql

Amigos buen día quisiera saber si existe un truco con for o while que me permita generar esté tipo de vista para una lista de inspección, la cual nos genere el estado de los aspectos de las ultimas 5 inspecciones :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se tiene por ahora esté código para sacar los datos de las tablas pero lo que no logro es que se acomode de esa manera me sale todo en vertical, esté es el código que llevo:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset", $user, $pass);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql4 = mysql_query("SELECT AspectosInspeccion_idAspectosInspeccion,Aprobado FROM RDInspeccion_has_AspectosInspeccion WHERE RDInspeccion_idRDInspeccion = '$id'", $link);
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    $valida = true;
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT cat.idRDInspeccion, cateins.idAspectosInspeccion, cat.IDEquipo_idIDEquipo, cateins.AspectosInspeccionNombre, catego.CategoriasInspeccionNombre, relinsp.Aprobado FROM RDInspeccion cat INNER JOIN Categoria_General_Inspeccion catid ON catid.idCategoria_General_Inspeccion=cat.Categoria_General_Inspeccion_idCategoria_General_Inspeccion INNER JOIN CategoriasInspeccion catego ON cat.Categoria_General_Inspeccion_idCategoria_General_Inspeccion=catego.Categoria_General_Inspeccion_idCategoria_General_Inspeccion INNER JOIN AspectosInspeccion cateins ON cateins.CategoriasInspeccion_idCategoriasInspeccion=catego.idCategoriasInspeccion INNER JOIN RDInspeccion_has_AspectosInspeccion relinsp ON cateins.idAspectosInspeccion=relinsp.AspectosInspeccion_idAspectosInspeccion WHERE cat.IDEquipo_idIDEquipo= '$idEquipo'");
    $sth->execute();

$IDAspectosInspeccion = $sth->fetchAll();

    var_dump($IDAspectosInspeccion);

    while ($valida==true){
        $RDIDInspeccionAnterior=$RDIDInspeccion;

        $NCategoriasAnterior=$AspectoCategoria;
        $AspectoID = $IDAspectosInspeccion[$i][1];
        $Aprovado = $IDAspectosInspeccion[$i][5];
        $RDIDInspeccion = $IDAspectosInspeccion[$i][0];
        $AspectoInspeccionNombre= $IDAspectosInspeccion[$i][3];
        $AspectoCategoria=$IDAspectosInspeccion[$i][4]; 



        $sql5 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT AspectosInspeccionNombre, CategoriasInspeccion_idCategoriasInspeccion FROM AspectosInspeccion WHERE idAspectosInspeccion = '$AspectoID'", $link);

        if ($validador = mysql_num_rows ($sql5) == 0)
        {
            $valida=false;
        }

            $NombreAspecto = $AspectoInspeccionNombre;
            $NCategorias = $AspectoCategoria;



        $validacat=true;
        if ($NCategoriasAnterior==$NCategorias){$validacat=false;}
            if ($NCategorias) {

                if ($validacat==true){

        echo "<tr height=20 style='mso-height-source:userset;height:15.0pt'>
  <td colspan=2 height=20 class=xl99 style='height:15.0pt;width:154pt'>".$NCategorias."<span style='mso-spacerun:yes'> </span></td>
  <td class=xl75 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>SI</td>
  <td class=xl75 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>NO</td>
  <td class=xl75 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>SI</td>
  <td class=xl75 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>NO</td>
   <td class=xl75 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>SI</td>
  <td class=xl75 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>NO</td> 
   <td class=xl75 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>SI</td>
  <td class=xl75 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>NO</td> 
   <td class=xl75 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>SI</td>
  <td class=xl75 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>NO</td> 
  <td></td>
 </tr>";
}}



            if($NombreAspecto){
        echo "<tr height=30 style='mso-height-source:userset;height:23.1pt'>
  <td colspan=2 height=30 class=xl100 style='height:23.1pt;
  width:154pt'>".$NombreAspecto."</td>";

            if ($Aprovado == "Rechazado")
        {
            $SeAprueba = "";
            $NOAprueba = "X";
        }
        else 
        {
            $SeAprueba = "X";
            $NOAprueba = "";
        }


                echo "<td class=xl77 style='border-top:none;border-left:none' align='center'>".$SeAprueba."</td>
  <td class=xl77 style='border-top:none;border-left:none' align='center'>".$NOAprueba."</td>";
                }
                $i++;
    }



        echo "<td></td></tr>";




    ?>
```

Esto es lo que obtenemos con el siguiente código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco su tiempo en responder. Con for casi sale pero se nos desplazaba la tabla.
Se hace una consulta a 3 tablas para generar el reporte.
Sería de gran ayuda que nos dieran alguna sugerencia o tip.
Si necesitan más datos con gusto se pueden proporcionar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En todos los casos es necesario rellenar crear todas las casillas de cada columna para que la tabla quede completa, sino queda con ese aspecto de desplazado a la izquierda, y siempre respetando su posición respecto al correspondiente encabezado.

Sería algo así, considerando que evaluais 6 casos o inspecciones con SI/NO por aspecto:

```
if ($NombreAspecto) {
  echo "<tr height=30 style='mso-height-source:userset;height:23.1pt'>";
   echo "<td colspan=2 height=30 class=xl100 style='height:23.1pt;width:154pt'>".$NombreAspecto."</td>";
   for ($c=1; $c<7; $c++) {
     //He supuesto una variable $caso que indica el número de caso del 1 al 6, y que supongo podéis definir a partir de vuestros resultados
    if ($caso==$c) {
     if ($AprovadoCaso == "Rechazado") {
        $SeAprueba = "";
        $NOAprueba = "X";
     } else {
        $SeAprueba = "X";
        $NOAprueba = "";
     }
    } else {
      //Si el caso no existe o no se evalua dejamos las casillas vacías
      $SeAprueba = "";
      $NOAprueba = "";
    }
     echo "<td class=xl77 style='border-top:none;border-left:none' align='center'>".$SeAprueba."</td>";
     echo "<td class=xl77 style='border-top:none;border-left:none' align='center'>".$NOAprueba."</td>";
   }
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Espero que os sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias buen tip para realizar el llenado de las columnas que no llevan datos, logre avanzar un poco, ahora me falta que no se dupliquen y las x se desplacen a los lados.